# Unable to locate the element using css selector[JAVA]

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Website: http://www.javatpoint.com/

Steps : First click on **JAVA**=>Scroll down and click on **Java String** => **Substring**

I'm trying to locate the webelement using cssSelector, but not able to locate the element whereas I'm able to locate the same using xpath.

[image]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[text()='Substring']"));
```

css Selectors I've tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>a[text='Substring']"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>a:contains('Substring')"));
```

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Java String')]"));`

Comment: That's right, you cannot use text content to locate element with `CSS` selector. What's your **question**?

Comment: I have gone through some documents on internet and comes to know that we can locate the text in an element with CSS Selector. But i am not able to locate it using CSS Selector.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you cannot locate an element by contained text using CSS selectors. To do that, you'll have to use an XPath.

But... there is an alternative CSS selector that will work here, `a[href='substring']`. This matches based on the href attribute of the A tag which, at least according to the posted HTML, is unique on the page and should work.

Comment: @ JeffCThank you for the comment .I already checked it, it works fine but I am only concerned about the **innertext**.

Comment: As at least 4 people have already stated, you can't use CSS selectors on innerText.

Comment: Yes, I got it now.

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You **can't select inner text using cssSelector**, it is not possible to do that.
If you need to do that use xPath instead.

Comment: I wouldn't claim that. Maybe you need to rephrase your answer as it seems that "innerHTML" is not what you actually want to use:)

Comment: Ok, inner text. :)